# Extending clusters by using USB hubs

Tags: usb, cluster, hub

Just heard of this *"cluster HAT"* which is basically a USB hub. Assembly is quiet simple. For me is 4 zeros not enough. So can I use normal **larger** hub to make a bigger cluster?

***Most important*** of all and if possible, which is the image I should install? By image I don't mean some picture but the OS to be flashed on the SD card.

Comment: Why? If you use a Pi4 it will outperform 10 Zeros (even if you could buy 10) and be cheaper.

Comment: @user135142 it seems you have lost access to the account you used to post this question. If you visit this [page](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) in the [Help center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) you can request for the accounts to be merged.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a HAT to create a cluster -- you don't need any additional hardware.  Usually pi's with ethernet jacks are connected via an ethernet switch, but since Zero's don't have that, apparently this can be done via wifi:

https://www.hackster.io/sridhar-rajagopal/raspberry-pi-zero-cluster-computing-fun-77a028

The only thing besides the zero used in that demo is a plastic case.  I don't know if there is a limit to the number that can be used, but eight or ten should be fine.